# CSS Animations work in CodePen, but they don't work after putting them in ASP.Net project

Tags: html, css, css-animations, asp.net-core-2.0

I've made a certain design in [codepen](https://codepen.io/ObsidianTech/project/editor/ZRRYLj) with a background animation, and it works there, but it doesn't work when I put it in my ASP.Net Core project. I know I'm referencing the file correctly because the background color does show, it just doesn't animate. I thought it was just an issue with Chrome, but it doesn't work in Firefox either. The only thing I haven't tested was to see if it worked in regular IIS instead of IIS Express.

Code:

CSS:

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:0 0;
}

.parallaxBackground {
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.colorcycle {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(271deg, #e7ff26, #2ecc00, #ff3b00, #2a9fff);
    background-size: 800% 800%;
    -webkit-animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
    -o-animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
    animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;

    -webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
        0% {
            background-position: 92% 0%
        }

        50% {
            background-position: 9% 100%
        }

        100% {
            background-position: 92% 0%
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
        0% {
            background-position: 92% 0%
        }

        50% {
            background-position: 9% 100%
        }

        100% {
            background-position: 92% 0%
        }
    }

    @-o-keyframes AnimationName {
        0% {
            background-position: 92% 0%
        }

        50% {
            background-position: 9% 100%
        }

        100% {
            background-position: 92% 0%
        }
    }

    @keyframes AnimationName {
        0% {
            background-position: 92% 0%
        }

        50% {
            background-position: 9% 100%
        }

        100% {
            background-position: 92% 0%
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <!--Parallax Landing Section-->
    <div class="parallaxBackground">
        <div class="colorcycle">testing testing testing </div>
    </div>
    <!--Parallax Landing Section-->
</body>
```

**Edit:** So, I tested it out separate from everything. I just made a plain folder on the desktop and put my HTML and CSS in their respective files and tried it like that. No other references to any JS,Bootstrap or anything else. Got the same issue. So I don't think it's something in my project blocking it, it has to be the way it's being processed. The only thing I can think of is that on Codepen, they CSS is in a .scss file, but I didn't think that would make a difference. I'll test that out but other than that, I have no idea. I'll just need to find an alternative.

Comment: see nothing on jsfiddle neither :/

Comment: Given that it works in CodePen but not in your project, I would think there is something conflicting in your project. The first place I would check would be the Dev Tools to make sure there is no other CSS conflicting with the animation styles you have here. From there, I would check to make sure the JavaScript is being fired correctly. This could be done with adding some breakpoints or console.logs to your code to test.

Comment: Make sure you are giving the correct location for CSS in your project.

Comment: So, I looked in to that. Would Less be a viable way to alleviate that issue?  Or would it be better to start ripping out the other CSS/JS code that I have? I actually have a few libraries and templates that I had added to the project that I am no longer using and I planned on removing them from the project anyways.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's pulling from the correct location because the other styles in that file are still working. It's just the animation that's not.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. In SASS, there are nested selectors, but it doesn't work in normal CSS. I just had to remove them from the class and that made it work.

```
.colorcycle {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(271deg, #e7ff26, #2ecc00, #ff3b00, #2a9fff);
    background-size: 800% 800%;
    -webkit-animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
    -o-animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
    animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
    0% {
        background-position: 92% 0%
    }

    50% {
        background-position: 9% 100%
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 92% 0%
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
    0% {
        background-position: 92% 0%
    }

    50% {
        background-position: 9% 100%
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 92% 0%
    }
}

@-o-keyframes AnimationName {
    0% {
        background-position: 92% 0%
    }

    50% {
        background-position: 9% 100%
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 92% 0%
    }
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
    0% {
        background-position: 92% 0%
    }

    50% {
        background-position: 9% 100%
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 92% 0%
    }
}
```